# Jest/Enzyme testing: expect.toContain(img)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I want to write a test using Jest/Enzyme that tests whether the correct image is returned depending on a condition. I currently have it passing with `expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('<img class="card-img CardImage" src="something.png" alt="Icon"/>');`
 but I was wondering if there was any way I could just test have it return that it contains an image with `className=CardImage`?

For example, it would be something along the lines of `expect(wrapper.html().img.className).toContain('CardImage')`. I've been searching online but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the method [hasClass](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/hasClass.html).

I suggest you to add an `id`, it will be easier to locate the image.

Here is an example:

```
expect(wrapper.find('my-image-id').hasClass('CardImage')).to.equal(true);
```